# Multiple Audio File Read blocks and a button Simulink

Tags: matlab, file, audio, simulink

I am trying to reproduce different audio files in Simulink, a different audio each time a push a button.
I configure a button via GPIO pin and, each time I push it, I modify an output of my System Object with the intenction of manage the audio file that I want to reproduce. I use Audio File Read and I have tried with separates enable subsystems and with switch case, but never works fine. The first audio starts reproducing, but whe I push the button, it doesn't work fine.

Thanks

Comment: You need to explain more on "doesn't work fine" for people to help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.